# Theorem on primitive n-th root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

My manual states the following theorem and its corollary. I don't understand the proof of the corollary:

**Theorem** Let $ζ$ be a primitive *n*-th root of unity and let $k$ be an integer, then $ζ^k$ has order $n/(n,k)$.

We put $\delta = GCD(n,k)$.

**Corollary** The primitive $n$-th roots of unity are

$ζ_{n,k} = \cos \frac{2\pi k}{n} + i \sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} = ζ_n^k$

where $(n,k)=1$ and $1\le k \lt n$

**Proof**. Indeed from $(ζ^k)^{n/\delta}$ = 1

it follows that $(ζ^k)$ is primitive if and only if $\delta = 1$

Now, I don't understand why has it to be $\delta = 1$, since $(ζ^n) = 1$ owing to primitivity, I should have

$(ζ^k)^{n/\delta}$ =  $(ζ^n)^{k/\delta}$ = 1

whatever delta. I'm not sure what I'm misinterpreting of the theorem (Is maybe $\zeta$ not primitive?).

Comment: What is $\delta$? Are you sure it's not "$\zeta^k$ has order $n/(n,k)$? Or it could be that the author defines $\delta:=(n,k)$ and says "$\zeta^k$ has order $n/\delta$"?

Comment: For reference, could you post a picture of the text in question and the name of the book in your post?

Comment: you're right! I made a mistake

Comment: your proof is more compelling than the one the manual gives, thanks

Comment: If $\delta\neq 1$, then $n/\delta\lt n$ which, along with $(\zeta^k)^{n/\delta}=1$ suggests that $\zeta^k$ is not a primitive $n$-th root of unity since it equals to $1$ for a smaller power than $n$

Comment: I don't understand where it deduced that $(\zeta^k)^{n/\delta}=1$. Isn't $(\zeta^k)^{n/\delta}=1$ true for every $\delta$ as I tried to show in the question?

Comment: Yes, the equality is true for every $\delta$ that divides $n$ but then $\zeta^k$ is not primitive anymore. For example, $(-1)$ is a 4th root of unity but it is not a primitive one since $(-1)^2=1$ and $2\lt 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem says that if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then the order of $\zeta^k$ is $n/(n,k) = n/\delta$.

But $\zeta^k$ is a *primitive* $n$-th root of unity iff its order is $n$, i.e. $n/\delta = n$ which is equivalent to $\delta = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion may come from the notion of *"being primitive"*. Though it is not mentioned in your question, a root of unity is primitive *of a certain order*. If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then $\zeta^k$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity if and only if $(n,k)=1$, and in general $\zeta^k$ is a primitive $\tfrac{n}{(n,k)}$-th root of unity.

For example, if $\zeta$ is a primitive sixth root of unity, then so is $\zeta^5=\zeta^{-1}$. Of course $\zeta^3=-1$ is *not* a primitive sixth root of unity; it is a primitive second root of unity. And indeed $\tfrac{6}{(6,3)}=2$.

So really your proof is fine, it just doesn't prove what you may think it proves; the identities
$$(\zeta^k)^{n/\delta}=(\zeta^n)^{k/\delta}=1^{k/\delta}=1,$$
shows that the order of $\zeta^k$ divides $\tfrac{n}{\delta}$. A simple argument shows that the order of $\zeta^k$ is precisely $\tfrac{n}{\delta}$, which shows that $\zeta^k$ is a primitive $\tfrac{n}{\delta}$-th root of unity. In particular this shows that $\zeta^k$ is *not* a primitive $n$-th root of unity if $\delta\neq1$!